# Player can't attack any more? (aRPG - Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey every one need some help, I'm making an aRPG and decided to add some special attacks, all was going well - but now I can't seem to attack the enemy, yet he can still attack me.

I'll attach 2 scripts, the first is the player combat, and the second is the special attack script. I was coding the special attack last, how ever can't seem to find what's causing the problem.

Here's the player combat (only attached what matters):

```
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !specialAttack)
    {
        inAction = true;
    }

    if(inAction)
    {
        if(attackFunction (0, 1, KeyCode.Space))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            inAction = false;
        }
    }
    die ();
}

public bool attackFunction(int stunSeconds, double scaledDamage, KeyCode key)
{
    if(Input.GetKey(key)&&inRange ())
    {
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play(attack.name);
        ClickToMove.attack = true;

        if(opponent!=null)
        {
            transform.LookAt(opponent.transform.position);
        }
    }
```

and here's the special attack script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpecialAttack : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public combat player;
    public KeyCode key;
    public double damagePercentage;
    public int stunTime;
    public bool inAction;

    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(key) && !player.specialAttack)
        {
            player.resetAttackFunction();
            player.specialAttack = true;
            inAction = true;
        }

        if(inAction)
        {
            if(player.attackFunction(stunTime, damagePercentage, key))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                inAction = false;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

If anyone could help me fix this problem I'd really appreciate it, I don't know what's wrong but I have a feeling it's some where in the Special Attack script, as the animation seems to reset and not let me attack.

Please help :)

Comment: The way this is coded, if you had a special attack it would never attack since inAction is only true if Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !specialAttack

Comment: Since you can't attack at all I would suggest adding a (few) `Debug.Log` or some breakpoints to check your `inAction` variable.

Answer (score 1):

There can be something inside the inRange() function. It seems like you dont have any code inside this if statement.

```
if(player.attackFunction(stunTime, damagePercentage, key))
{

}
```